# jquery chosen plugin with dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery plugin chosen. I have that working as I want. My issue is using it with a dynamic table. The initial row works but when a new row is added to the table the newly added chosen doesn't work. I did find a question on here about using .on but am completely lost as to how to go about this.

**jQuery Code for chosen plugin**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chosen.css" />

<script>

    $(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    });    

</script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
        <form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
            <p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete last row.</p>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add"/>
             <input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Delete"/>



            <br>

            <table id="myTable" class="form">

                 <tr id="heading">
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Unit Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Code</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Model Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Scope</font></b></th>
                </tr>   

                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobNumber[]" value="<?php echo $JobNumber;?>" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value="<?php echo $JobNumber;?>-01" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="JobCode[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                            <option></option>
                            <option>F</option>
                            <option>FS</option>
                            <option>PD</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ModelNumber[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                    </td>

        <td>
           <select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select Scope's" name="Scope[]" style="width:300px;" required>
                          <option value="100OA">100OA</option>
                            <option value="BTank">BTank</option>
                            <option value="WSEcon">WSEcon</option>
                            <option value="NetPkg">NetPkg</option>
                            <option value="CstmCtrl">CstmCtrl</option>
                            <option value="CstmFef">CstmRef</option>
                            <option value="CstmSM">CstmSM</option>
                            <option value="CstmHV">CstmHV</option>
                            <option value="CPCtrl">CPCtrl</option>
                            <option value="DesiHW">DesiHW</option>
                            <option value="DigScroll">DigScroll</option>
                            <option value="DigScroll">DFGas</option>
                            <option value="DWall">DWall</option>
                            <option value="MZ-DD">MZ-DD</option>
                            <option value="DPP">DPP</option>
                            <option value="Encl">Encl</option>
                            <option value="PlateHX">PlateHX</option>
                            <option value="ERW">ERW</option>
                            <option value="ERWModule">ERWModule</option>
                            <option value="ERVMod">ERVMod</option>
                            <option value="EvapBP">EvapBP</option>
                            <option value="PreEvap">PreEvap</option>
                            <option value="XP">XP</option>
                            <option value="Extend">Extend</option>
                            <option value="FanWall">FanWall</option>
                            <option value="FillStat">FillStat</option>
                            <option value="FFilt">FFilt</option>
                            <option value="PFilt">PFilt</option>
                            <option value="CarbFilt">CarbFilt</option>
                            <option value="CustFilt">CustFilt</option>
                            <option value="MGH(H)">MGH(H)</option>
                            <option value="GHeat">GHeat</option>
                            <option value="HighStatic">HighStatic</option>
                            <option value="HGBP">HGBP</option>
                            <option value="HGRH">HGRH</option>
                            <option value="HPConv">HPConv</option>
                            <option value="GFHumid">GFHumid</option>
                            <option value="TOHumid">TOHumid</option>
                            <option value="MHGRH">MHGRH</option>
                            <option value="LowAF">LowAF</option>
                            <option value="LowAFSF">LowAFSF</option>
                            <option value="LowAmbient">LowAmbient</option>
                            <option value="MEHeat(R)">MEHeat(R)</option>
                            <option value="MEHeat(I)">MEHeat(I)</option>
                            <option value="HGH(R)">MGH(R)</option>
                            <option value="MGH(H)">MGH(H)</option>
                            <option value="MtrRR">MtrRR</option>
                            <option value="MotorGM">MotorGM</option>
                            <option value="MS-Mod">MZ-Mod</option>
                            <option value="NatConv">NatConv</option>
                            <option value="OAFMS">OAFMS</option>
                            <option value="OSMotor">OSMotor</option>
                            <option value="MZ-VAV">MZ-VAV</option>
                            <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
                            <option value="PumpPkg">PumpPkg</option>
                            <option value="PipePkg">PipePkg</option>
                            <option value="ServLite">ServLite</option>
                            <option value="SparkRes">SparkRes</option>
                            <option value="SSLube">SSLube</option>
                            <option value="UVLights">UVLights</option>
                            <option value="VSComp">VSComp</option>
                            <option value="LCVAV">LCVAV</option>
                            <option value="XFVAV">XFVAV</option>
                            <option value="WCCond">WCCond</option>
                            <option value="WSHPConv">WSHPConv</option>
                            <option value="3RConv">3RConv</option>
                            <option value="WiringGM">WiringGM</option>
                            <option value="XFan">XFan</option>
                            <option value="RFan">RFan</option>
                            <option value="SFan">SFan</option>
                            <option value="OAHood">OAHood</option>
                            <option value="XAHood">XAHood</option>
                            <option value="XALouver">XALouver</option>
                            <option value="OALouver">OALouver</option>
                            <option value="SteamCoil">SteamCoil</option>
                            <option value="HWCoil">HWCoil</option>
                            <option value="CHWCoil">CHWCoil</option>
                            <option value="CondCoil">CondCoil</option>
                            <option value="DXCoil">DXCoil</option>
                            <option value="F&BP">F&BP</option>
                            <option value="Xfrmr">Xfrmr</option>
                            <option value="WCCond">WCCond</option>
                            <option value="PLFrHX">PlFrHX</option>
                        </select>

        </td>

            </table>
```

**JS code for adding rows to table**

```
<script>

    function incrementUnitId(unitId) {
        var arr = unitId.split('-');
        if (arr.length === 1) {return;} // The unit id is not valid;
        var number = parseInt(arr[1]) + 1;
        return arr[0] + '-' + (number < 10 ? 0 : '') + number;
        }

    function addRow() {                
        var row = document.getElementById("tableRow"); // find row to copy
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append to
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
        row.id = "oldRow"; // We want to take the last value inserted
        clone.cells[1].childNodes[1].value = incrementUnitId(clone.cells[1].childNodes[1].value)
        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
        }


    function deleteRow() {
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
        } 

</script>
```

Comment: Apply your plugin in `addRow` function. `$('.chzn-select', clone).chosen();`

Comment: Sorry bare with me. But adding that to the add row function. Did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

> hey, I know i'm little late but you need to destroy your chosen and
> then append and recontruct it like this:

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    });    

        function addRow() {                
            var row = document.getElementById("tableRow"); // find row to copy
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append  
             $(".chzn-select").chosen("destroy")
            var clone = $('#newId').get(0).outerHTML;
          var tblRow = '<tr><td> <input type="text"></td>';
                tblRow += '<td> <input type="text"></td>';
                tblRow += '<td>'+$("#selectJob").html()+'</td>';
                            tblRow += '<td> <input type="text"></td>';

                tblRow += '<td >'+clone+'</td>';
                tblRow += '<td   </td> <td   </td> ';
                   tblRow+='</tr>';
                $("#myTable").append(tblRow); 
                
               $('.chzn-select').chosen()
             }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chosen.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
        <form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
            <p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete last row.</p>

            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add"/>
             <input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Delete"/>
              <br>

            <table id="myTable" class="form">

                 <tr id="heading">
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Unit Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Job Code</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Model Number</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font size="4">Scope</font></b></th>
                </tr>   

                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="JobNumber[]" value=" " readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value=" " readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <div id="selectJob"> 
                        <select id="JobCode" name="JobCode[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                            <option></option>
                            <option>F</option>
                            <option>FS</option>
                            <option>PD</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ModelNumber[]" style="background-color:#FFE68C" required>
                    </td>

        <td>
           <select class="chzn-select" id="newId" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select Scope's" name="Scope[]" style="width:300px;" required>
                          <option value="100OA">100OA</option>
                            <option value="BTank">BTank</option>
                            <option value="WSEcon">WSEcon</option>
                            <option value="NetPkg">NetPkg</option>
                            <option value="CstmCtrl">CstmCtrl</option>
                            <option value="CstmFef">CstmRef</option>
                            <option value="CstmSM">CstmSM</option>
                            <option value="CstmHV">CstmHV</option>
                            <option value="CPCtrl">CPCtrl</option>
                            <option value="DesiHW">DesiHW</option>
                            <option value="DigScroll">DigScroll</option>
                            <option value="DigScroll">DFGas</option>
                            <option value="DWall">DWall</option>
                            <option value="MZ-DD">MZ-DD</option>
                            <option value="DPP">DPP</option>
                            <option value="Encl">Encl</option>
                            <option value="PlateHX">PlateHX</option>
                            <option value="ERW">ERW</option>
                            <option value="ERWModule">ERWModule</option>
                            <option value="ERVMod">ERVMod</option>
                            <option value="EvapBP">EvapBP</option>
                            <option value="PreEvap">PreEvap</option>
                            <option value="XP">XP</option>
                            <option value="Extend">Extend</option>
                            <option value="FanWall">FanWall</option>
                            <option value="FillStat">FillStat</option>
                            <option value="FFilt">FFilt</option>
                            <option value="PFilt">PFilt</option>
                            <option value="CarbFilt">CarbFilt</option>
                            <option value="CustFilt">CustFilt</option>
                            <option value="MGH(H)">MGH(H)</option>
                            <option value="GHeat">GHeat</option>
                            <option value="HighStatic">HighStatic</option>
                            <option value="HGBP">HGBP</option>
                            <option value="HGRH">HGRH</option>
                            <option value="HPConv">HPConv</option>
                            <option value="GFHumid">GFHumid</option>
                            <option value="TOHumid">TOHumid</option>
                            <option value="MHGRH">MHGRH</option>
                            <option value="LowAF">LowAF</option>
                            <option value="LowAFSF">LowAFSF</option>
                            <option value="LowAmbient">LowAmbient</option>
                            <option value="MEHeat(R)">MEHeat(R)</option>
                            <option value="MEHeat(I)">MEHeat(I)</option>
                            <option value="HGH(R)">MGH(R)</option>
                            <option value="MGH(H)">MGH(H)</option>
                            <option value="MtrRR">MtrRR</option>
                            <option value="MotorGM">MotorGM</option>
                            <option value="MS-Mod">MZ-Mod</option>
                            <option value="NatConv">NatConv</option>
                            <option value="OAFMS">OAFMS</option>
                            <option value="OSMotor">OSMotor</option>
                            <option value="MZ-VAV">MZ-VAV</option>
                            <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
                            <option value="PumpPkg">PumpPkg</option>
                            <option value="PipePkg">PipePkg</option>
                            <option value="ServLite">ServLite</option>
                            <option value="SparkRes">SparkRes</option>
                            <option value="SSLube">SSLube</option>
                            <option value="UVLights">UVLights</option>
                            <option value="VSComp">VSComp</option>
                            <option value="LCVAV">LCVAV</option>
                            <option value="XFVAV">XFVAV</option>
                            <option value="WCCond">WCCond</option>
                            <option value="WSHPConv">WSHPConv</option>
                            <option value="3RConv">3RConv</option>
                            <option value="WiringGM">WiringGM</option>
                            <option value="XFan">XFan</option>
                            <option value="RFan">RFan</option>
                            <option value="SFan">SFan</option>
                            <option value="OAHood">OAHood</option>
                            <option value="XAHood">XAHood</option>
                            <option value="XALouver">XALouver</option>
                            <option value="OALouver">OALouver</option>
                            <option value="SteamCoil">SteamCoil</option>
                            <option value="HWCoil">HWCoil</option>
                            <option value="CHWCoil">CHWCoil</option>
                            <option value="CondCoil">CondCoil</option>
                            <option value="DXCoil">DXCoil</option>
                            <option value="F&BP">F&BP</option>
                            <option value="Xfrmr">Xfrmr</option>
                            <option value="WCCond">WCCond</option>
                            <option value="PLFrHX">PlFrHX</option>
                        </select>

        </td>

            </table>
```